Problema en ruta dinamica Nextjs
Estoy utilizando este componente page.tsx alojado en profile/[id] (ruta dinamica de nextjs). Y tengo dos problemas que me surjen.
En el localhost cuando estoy seteado como empresa me indica que no hay un curriculum para mostrar (los datos de profile y los posteos los encuentra sin problema)
En el localhost cuando ingreso como "profesional" (No empresa) me muestra todo sin errores.
Pero cuando despliego el sitio con vercel e intento acceder a pesar de ver que la URL toma el numero de usuario (ej: https://emplearg.vercel.app/profile/user_2mTvfwiw77NUHskNFRlXfr5Ff1R)
Me muestra el error
const fetchProfile = async () => {
      if (!id) {
        setError('Usuario ID no está defined');
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

Y no me renderiza nada, ni posteos, ni datos de profile ni de curriculum.
A las api las probe todas desde insomia y aplicando ese numero de usuario accedo a la informacion guardada.
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useAuth } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Spinner from '@/components/spinner';


interface Profile {
  _id: string;
  clerkUserId: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  isEmpresa: boolean;
  curriculumEmpresa?: CurriculumEmpresa;
  curriculum?: Curriculum;
}

interface Curriculum {
  provincia: string;
  ciudad: string;
  barrio: string;
  rubro: string;
  profesion: string;
  experienciaAnios: number;
  estudios: string;
  cursos: string[];
  habilidad: string;
  habilidad1: string;
  habilidad2: string;
  bio: string;
  disponibilidad: string;
}

interface CurriculumEmpresa {
  provincia: string;
  ciudad: string;
  barrio: string;
  rubro: string;
  calle: string;
  numero: string;
  actividad: string;
  cuit: string;
  telefono: string;
  whatsapp: string;
  website: string;
}

interface Post {
  _id: string;
  user: {
    userImage: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  };
  text: string;
  imageUrl?: string;
  createdAt: string;
}

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { isLoaded } = useAuth();
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState<Profile | null>(null);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useParams id:', id); // Log para verificar el id obtenido
    if (!isLoaded) return;
  
    const fetchProfile = async () => {
      if (!id) {
        setError('Usuario ID no está defined');
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }
  
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/profile/${id}`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          const errorMessage = await response.text();
          throw new Error(`Error al obtener perfil: ${errorMessage}, estado: ${response.status}`);
        }
  
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Fetched data:', data); // Log para verificar los datos obtenidos
  
        setProfile({
          ...data.user,
          curriculum: data.user.isEmpresa ? undefined : data.curriculum,
          curriculumEmpresa: data.user.isEmpresa ? data.curriculumEmpresa : undefined
        });
  
        console.log('Updated profile:', {
          ...data.user,
          curriculum: data.user.isEmpresa ? undefined : data.curriculum,
          curriculumEmpresa: data.user.isEmpresa ? data.curriculumEmpresa : undefined
        }); // Log para verificar el estado actualizado
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener perfil:', error);
        setError('No se pudo obtener el perfil');
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
  
    fetchProfile();
  }, [id, isLoaded]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserPosts = async () => {
      if (!profile?.clerkUserId) {
        console.error('Clerk User ID is not defined');
        return;
      }
  
      console.log('Profile:', profile);
      console.log('Fetching posts for Clerk User ID:', profile.clerkUserId);
  
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/users/${profile.clerkUserId}/posts`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Posts data:', data);
        setPosts(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user posts:', error);
      }
    };
  
    if (profile) {
      fetchUserPosts();
    }
  }, [profile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (profile) {
      console.log('Profile:', profile);
      console.log('Curriculum Empresaurio:', profile.curriculumEmpresa);
      console.log('Curriculum:', profile.curriculum);
    }
  }, [profile]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div className='flex justify-center w-screen h-screen '><Spinner /></div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  }

  if (!profile) {
    return <div>No se encontró el perfil.</div>;
  }

  const renderCurriculum = (profile: Profile) => {
    if (profile.isEmpresa) {
      if (profile.curriculumEmpresa) {
        return (
          <div className='flex flex-col mt-4 space-y-4'>
          <p className='font-bold'>Provincia: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.provincia}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Ciudad: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.ciudad}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Barrio: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.barrio}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Rubro: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.rubro}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Calle: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.calle}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Número: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.numero}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Actividad: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.actividad}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>CUIT: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.cuit}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Teléfono: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.telefono}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>WhatsApp: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.whatsapp}</span></p>
          <p className='font-bold'>Website: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculumEmpresa.website}</span></p>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return <p>No hay currículum disponible.</p>;
      }
    } else {
      if (profile.curriculum) {
        return (
          <div className='flex flex-col mt-4 space-y-4'>
            <p className='font-bold'>Provincia: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.provincia}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Ciudad: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.ciudad}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Barrio: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.barrio}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Rubro: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.rubro}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Profesión: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.profesion}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Años de Experiencia: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.experienciaAnios}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Estudios: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.estudios}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Cursos: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.cursos.join(', ')}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Habilidades: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.habilidad}, {profile.curriculum.habilidad1}, {profile.curriculum.habilidad2}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Bio: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.bio}</span></p>
            <p className='font-bold'>Disponibilidad: <span className='font-normal'>{profile.curriculum.disponibilidad}</span></p>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return <p>No hay currículum disponible.</p>;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex w-screen'>
      <div className="grid grid-col w-full md:grid-cols-2 mt-2 mb-4 mr-4 p-4 gap-4 rounded-lg z-[100] bg-gradient-to-tr from-blue-400 to-green-200 overflow-y-auto">
        <div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
          <div className='flex flex-col items- md:gap-2 gap-1 z-[20]'>
            <h1 className="text-xl md:translate-x-">Perfil Público</h1>
            <div className='flex flex-row items-center '>
              <Image
                src={profile.imageUrl}
                alt="profile picture"
                width={200}
                height={200}
                className="z-[10] w-12 md:w-24 h-12 md:h-24 hover:w-48 hover:h-48 rounded-full hover:rounded-xl ease-in-out duration-500 shadow-lg"
              />
              <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <p className='text-xs md:text-base font-bold ml-1'>{`${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`}</p>
                <Link href={`mailto:${profile.email}`} target='_blank'>
                  <p className='text-xs md:text-base font-normal ml-1 text-blue-700 underline'>{profile.email}</p>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            
            <div className='flex justify-center'>
              <div className='flex flex-row justify-center items-center space-x-1 border-[1px] rounded-lg p-2 border-gray-100 bg-gradient-to-tl from-blue-400 hover:scale-125 ease-in-out duration-500'>
                <Image 
                  width={50}  
                  height={50}
                  src='/chat.png'
                  alt='messageicon'
                  className='w-4 md:w-8'
                />
                <p className='text-xs md:text-base text-gray-900'>Mensaje a</p>
                <span className='text-xs md:text-base text-gray-900'>{`${profile.firstName}`}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='flex flex-col items-start bg-white opacity-70 rounded-lg border-2 overflow-y-auto p-2'>
            {renderCurriculum(profile)}
          </div>
        </div>
   
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center bg-white opacity-70 rounded-lg border-2 p-2 '>
          <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold">Posteos</h3>
          {posts && posts.length > 0 ? (
            posts.map((post) => (
              <div key={post._id} className="w-full mb-4 p-4 border rounded-lg">
                <Image
                  src={post.user.userImage}
                  alt="user image"
                  width={50}
                  height={50}
                  className="rounded-full h-12 w-12"
                />
                <h3 className="text-lg font-bold">{post.user.firstName} {post.user.lastName}</h3>
                <p>{post.text}</p>
                {post.imageUrl && (
                  <Image
                    src={post.imageUrl}
                    alt="post image"
                    width={200}
                    height={200}
                    className="rounded-lg"
                  />
                )}
                <span className="text-xs text-gray-500">
                  {new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                </span>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>No hay posteos disponibles.</p>
          )}
        </div>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;

